# jquery Infinite scroll / conflict with numbers in the URL

Tags: jquery, ajax

as I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958672/jquery-infinite-scroll-images-load-twice). I have problems with the "next" selector. I think I know the reason now but I dont know how to fix it.

The console showed me, that the problem is my URL structure.

Example:

/gallery/category-a213/20.html (page 2)
/gallery/category-a213/40.html (page 3)

Console saying:

/gallery/category-a", "13/20.html"

I need the "a" (ID) in the category URL.

How can I change the jquery.infinitescroll.min.js to get the right path and dont use the first number in the URL for the next selector?

```
_determinepath: function(a) {
        var c = this.options;
        if (c.behavior && this["_determinepath_" + c.behavior] !== e) this["_determinepath_" + c.behavior].call(this, a);
        else {
            if (c.pathParse) return this._debug("pathParse manual"),
                c.pathParse(a, this.options.state.currPage + 1);
            if (a.match(/^(.*?)\b2\b(.*?$)/)) a = a.match(/^(.*?)\b2\b(.*?$)/).slice(1);
            else if (a.match(/^(.*?)2(.*?$)/)) {
                if (a.match(/^(.*?page=)2(\/.*|$)/)) return a = a.match(/^(.*?page=)2(\/.*|$)/).slice(1);
                a = a.match(/^(.*?)2(.*?$)/).slice(1)
            } else {
                if (a.match(/^(.*?page=)1(\/.*|$)/)) return a = a.match(/^(.*?page=)1(\/.*|$)/).slice(1);
                this._debug("Sorry, we couldn't parse your Next (Previous Posts) URL. Verify your the css selector points to the correct A tag. If you still get this error: yell, scream, and kindly ask for help at infinite-scroll.com.");
                c.state.isInvalidPage = !0
            }
            this._debug("determinePath", a);
            return a
        }
    },
```

Thank you

Comment: the infinite.min is to long but I copy and paste the determinepath: function in the question. I think thats the place where we need to change something?

Comment: "yell, scream, and kindly ask for help at infinite-scroll.com." - have you tried that?

Comment: well, I noticed that the support on infinite-scroll / githup isnt very  frequented. So I tried my luck here...